# Why doesn't the [committemplate] section do anything in my mercurial .hgrc?

Tags: mercurial

I have the following section in my `~/.hgrc` file. Other settings there work perfectly well.

However this:

```
[committemplate]
changeset = {desc}\n\n
    HG: Enter yo commit message.  Lines beginning with 'HG:' are removed.
    HG: {extramsg}
    HG: --
    HG: user: {author}\n{ifeq(p2rev, "-1", "",
   "HG: branch merge\n")
   }HG: branch '{branch}'\n{if(activebookmark,
   "HG: bookmark '{activebookmark}'\n")   }{subrepos %
   "HG: subrepo {subrepo}\n"              }{file_adds %
   "HG: added {file}\n"                   }{file_mods %
   "HG: changed {file}\n"                 }{file_dels %
   "HG: removed {file}\n"                 }{if(files, "",
   "HG: no files changed\n")}
```

Which I copied from [help page about hgrc](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/hgrc), and added the `yo`, to see if it worked. It didn't. I'm using mercurial 3.5, downloaded and installed today from https://www.mercurial-scm.org/

Comment: I just tried this (copying and pasting your example directly), and it worked for me just fine (with version 3.5 also). Both using `~/.hgrc` and `.hg/hgrc`. I'm not sure what could cause this to be ignored.

Comment: @ReimerBehrends wat. hm. What editor do you use? I'm also on mac os. Need to try on one of my linux boxen

Comment: Maybe you have defined it twice in one of the relevant hgrc files like the system-wide, your global, the repo-specific one?

Comment: @WayneWerner I'm using Vim on OS X, but the editor shouldn't matter (the message does not depend on your choice of editor). Does `hg config | grep committemplate` show your custom template?

Comment: Okay, I'm about as confused as I possibly can be. I *know* I was editing the hgrc file. I *know* I was writing out to it. But apparently I removed that section yesterday and when I put it back this morning everything works. (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻